# How can I get a Domain Controller to give me a ClickOnce Certificate

Tags: clickonce, dns, certificate

I need to get hold of a new ClickOnce Certificate because my temporary one has expired. My applications are only used internally so I'd like to get a **certificate from our Domain Controller** so installation does not have a security prompt (and doesn't expire a quickly)

There are a number of Questions that come close to my issue:
[Signing ClickOnce with a certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977621/signing-clickonce-with-a-certificate) (Very close)
[Visual Studio ClickOnce deployment - certificate expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121223/visual-studio-clickonce-deployment-certificate-expiration)
[How can I renew my expired ClickOnce certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280472/how-can-i-renew-my-expired-clickonce-certificate)

Comment: just trying to clarify.  your self-cert ran out and you don't want to pay for a third-party cert?  are you your own CA?

Comment: No I'm not a certificate authority. But my applications will only every be used within my Windows Domain. I remember being told (a long time ago now) that a Domain Controller is considered a Trusted Root so if it 'signs' the cert your application will be considered verified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Domain Controller is already trusted, it seems very natural to simply start up Certificate Services on that DC and turn it into a CA. Once you get that set up, you will be able to request Code Signing certificates from the developer PCs through the Certificates Snap-in (MMC). The certificates will be in the name of the developer but we like that where I work because it conveys accountability.

BTW, we are running that exact same configuration at my company and it works like a charm.